# Trying to make a selected file's data an array, but how?

Tags: java, arrays

Well, basically I want to be able to select a file with a bunch of number, print it's name and directory, and find the mode,  I think I got it figured out, but creating the array to hold my data is stumping me.  I feel like the answer is in front of me and it's really bugging me, help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

 public class ModeFinder 
 {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String filename;

        FileDialog filePicker = new FileDialog(new JFrame());
        filePicker.setVisible(true);

        filename = filePicker.getFile();
        String folderName = filePicker.getDirectory();
        filename = folderName + filename;
        System.out.println("filename = " +filename);

        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner fileReader;
        try
        {
            fileReader = new Scanner(inputFile);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException excp)
        {
            System.out.println("That's no file...");
        }

        int size = ;
        double[] a = new double[size];
        int maxValue = 0,
                maxCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; ++j) {
                if (a[j] == a[i]) ++count;
            }
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = (int) a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The most common grade is: " +maxValue);
    }
}
```

If I don't need to make an array, I won't mind you saying so.  I just need a way to make the numbers from a file be read and used to find the mode of said numbers.  Just a refresher, the mode is the number that appears most in a data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dedicated to using an array, you can pass through the file twice; once to get the number of doubles in the file, and once more to actually read in the values. This method will count the number of doubles in the given file:

```
public static int countDoubles(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    // Create a scanner to read the file.
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

    // Count of the doubles in the file.
    int count = 0;

    while (reader.hasNextDouble())
    {
        // Consume each double and increment the counter.
        count++;
        reader.nextDouble();
    }

    reader.close();
    return count;
}
```

This method will read the doubles from the file:

```
public static double[] readDoubles(File file, int numberOfDoubles) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    // Create a scanner to read the file.
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

    // Create an array to store the values.
    double[] values = new double[numberOfDoubles];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length && reader.hasNextDouble(); ++i)
    {
        // Consume each value and insert it into the array.
        values[i] = reader.nextDouble();
    }

    reader.close();
    return values;
}
```

However, it would be simpler (and more robust) to use a structure that will dynamically resize, like an `ArrayList<Double>`.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm really dumb and bad at arrays(maybe java in general), how do I print the mode though? Or at least plug it in with my mode code in my initial code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'mode'. As far as incorporating the code I posted, you can use the methods as-is by copying them into your class definition, or adapting the relevant portions to your needs.

Comment: The mode is the number which appears the most frequently in a set of numbers.  As I said, I have the way to select a file, I have the code necessary to calculate mode, the problem is getting the contents into an array that can be executed with my code.  Sorry if I sound kinda frustrated, but I still feel like the answer is right in my face and I can't see it

Comment: when toying with it more it seems to have worked, but something else happened so I'm opening a new question